# How to Decode from utf 8 to Clean Text

Tags: c#, utf-8, decode

Goal:
Decode from utf 8 to clean text

Problem:
Based on this code below, it doesn't want to decode from "masavÃ¤g" to "masaväg".

What part am I missing?

Thank you!

Info:
It works to decode from "masavÃ¤g" to "masaväg" in this page
https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode

```
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
    String unicodeString = "masavÃ¤g";
    // Encode the string.
    Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
    // Decode bytes back to string.
    String decodedString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);
```

Comment: you say "utf8" and "clean text" as though there's a difference. It is meaningless to talk about utf8 in terms of characters - utf8 is an *encoding*: what is more interesting is the *bytes*. What you *seem* to be asking is "I have some bytes that I've decoded incorrectly; how do I fix that?" - the answer is: don't decode them incorrectly in the first place...?

Answer (score 4):

The correct utf8 for `"masaväg"` is hex  6d 61 73 61 76 c3 a4 67

It looks like you've decoded this using the wrong encoding; we can figure out which that might be like so:

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("masaväg");
foreach(var enc in Encoding.GetEncodings())
{
    try
    {
        if(enc.GetEncoding().GetString(bytes) == "masavÃ¤g")
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{enc.CodePage} {enc.DisplayName}");
        }
    } catch { }
}
```

which outputs:

```
1252 Western European (Windows)
1254 Turkish (Windows)
28591 Western European (ISO)
28594 Baltic (ISO)
28599 Turkish (ISO)
65000 Unicode (UTF-7)
```

Now: I don't know which of those you used, but let's assume it was 1252.

So to reverse this mess (noting that this is **unreliable** and your data may already be corrupted irretreivably if you only have it as this garbled text data rather than as the underlying encoded bytes):

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
var bytes = enc.GetBytes("masavÃ¤g");
var viaUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(viaUtf8);
```

which outputs:

```
masaväg
```

Note the important thing here isn't that "masavÃ¤g" is "utf8" or that "masaväg" is "clean text"; rather: "masavÃ¤g" is what you get if you use the wrong encoding to decode bytes into text. In this case the correct encoding to use when decoding would have been utf8. It is only the binary data that "is utf8". Once it is text (a `string` in .NET terms): it is code-points. And "encoding" (such as utf8) *defines* how code-points map to bytes (that's literally what an "encoding" is).

Note: code-page 1252 is *often* what `Encoding.Default` is, hence why 1252 is a safe assumption. You should never ever use `Encoding.Default` *for anything*, frankly. You should always **know** what encoding you intend to use. I suggest we should submit a PR to rename `Encoding.Default` to `Encoding.PotLuck`.